# Creating WebReference or ServiceReference based on wsdl url in VS

Tags: c#, web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

When I try to add Web Reference or Service Reference to VS project based on working given [wsdl](http://91.239.129.38:1199/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/AxCustomerFindDev2IIS/xppservice.svc?wsdl) I've got error:

> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
>     - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>     - There was an error downloading  'ax2012int.senetic.local:1199/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/AxCustomerFindDev2IIS/xppservice.svc?wsdl=wsdl0'.
>     - The remote name could not be resolved: *** Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '[wsdl](http://91.239.129.38:1199/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/AxCustomerFindDev2IIS/xppservice.svc?wsdl)'. The HTTP request is 
>   unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="91.239.129.38"'. The remote server
>   returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.*

How can I add that service to the project without error.

1. I tried manually using wsdl.exe with url or downloaded file.
2. Also tried changing domain ax2012int.senetic.local to that 91.239.129.38
   with no luck.

Comment: maybe test and see if you can get to the wsdl in the browser--is it authentication? an issue with the service itself? can you call the service from a job in ax?